# Why is pyodbc returning an SSL error message for a specific data point each time I run a specific query?

Tags: docker, ssl, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am querying an (external) Azure SQL database within an Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container. I have installed pydobc without any (apparent) problems, and I am usually able to run queries without any problems. Sometimes they return results, sometimes they don't return any results (expected).

However, during my most recent test I always run into this error:

`pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number] (-1) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

This occurs after several successful queries of the same type and cursor, with the only difference being a specific ID that is templated into the query. There aren't any fancy functions in the query, just a few `SELECT` and `JOIN ... ON` statements and a single `WHERE` clause (which is the only difference between each of the queries).

I've tried removing/recreating the container and image (and reinstalling the requisite packages), but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server to see if that helps?

Comment: You need to connect to Azure SQL Database using Encrypt=True on the connection string.

Comment: Verify any proxy settings. The error seems to indicate issues communicating over SSL.

Comment: I will try those tomorrow. Are these issues that would suddenly appear for one query with the same cursor but not previous queries?

Comment: Currently using ODBC Driver 17, and the error still persists.